# Using many instances of 'gsub' in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm making a basic translator in Ruby (1.9.3). I'm pulling from a local test file ('a.txt') and using gsub to replace certain matches to mimic a translation from contemporary English to Middle/Early Modern English. I've run into a readability issue:

How can I make the large amount of gsub usage easier to read? I've attempted to use multiple lines starting with

```
def translate 
  @text.gsub(/my/, 'mine')
  @text.gsub(/\sis\s/, ' be ')
end
```

but this only prints the final gsub. I can only assume that the second request overwrites the first. I would like to avoid creating a giant line of gsub requests and I cannot seem to find a suitable answer.

Here is a sample of my current program:

```
lines = File.readlines('a.txt')
@text = lines.join

def translate 
  @text.gsub(/my/, 'mine').gsub(/\sis\s/, ' be ').gsub(/y\s/, 'ye ').gsub(/t\s/, 'te ').gsub(/t\,/, 'te,').gsub(/t\./, 'te.')
end

puts translate
```

I apologize in advance if this request seems thoroughly basic.
Cheers!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second call doesn't override the first.  The first call returns a copy of `@text` with the substitution made, but you aren't doing anything with that returned value.  If you want to modify `@text`, you need to use `gsub!` instead.  If you don't want to modify `@text`, then you need to chain the `gsub` calls instead.  For instance, if you have the mapping Hash from [slivu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13556720/1507392), this will return the translated text without actually modifying the `@text` instance variable:

```
def translate
  RegexMap.inject(@text) do |string, mapping|
    string.gsub(*mapping)
  end
end
```

The block passed to `inject` gets called once per mapping (key/value pair in `RegexMap`).  The first time, `string` is the value passed to `inject` - namely, `@text`.  After that, each subsequent call gets the return value of the previous call passed in as its `string` value. So it's as if you did this, but with the set of mappings more easily configurable:

```
@text.gsub(/my/,'mine').gsub(/\sis\s/, ' be ').gsub(/y\s/,'ye ').gsub....
```

Comment: what about this? :) `string.gsub(*kv)`

Answer (score 6):

The `String#gsub` method returns a new copy of the string with the substitution done, leaving the original string unmodified. Both of the substitutions in your first example are done, but the result of the first is discarded because it isn't assigned to anything. The result of the second one is returned as the result of the method.

If you instead use the `#gsub!` method, that will modify the original string with the results of the substitution, allowing an easier way to do multiple substitutions.

```
def translate 
  @text.gsub!(/my/, 'mine')
  @text.gsub!(/\sis\s/, ' be ')
  @text
end
```

If you don't want to modify the attribute on the object you could start the method with `text = @text.dup`, and then use the `text` variable in place of the `@text` attribute for the remainder of the method.

Comment: Be careful here, one subtle difference between `gsub` and `gsub!` is that `gsub` will return the original value if the pattern is not found, `gsub!` will assign a `nil` if the pattern is not found.

Answer (score 5):

more readable?

would you then consider to build a map and use a loop on it?

```
RegexMap = {
  /my/     => 'mine',
  /\sis\s/ => ' be ',
  /y\s/    => 'ye ',
  /t\s/    => 'te ',
  /t\,/    => 'te,',
  /t\./    => 'te.',
}
text = '123 my 456 is 123y 456t 123t, 456t.'
RegexMap.each_pair {|f,t| text = text.gsub(f, t)}
puts text

#=> 123 mine 456 be 123ye 456te 123te, 456te.
```

**Update:** as Mark suggested, using `gsub!` will avoid redundant copy/assign operations:

```
RegexMap.each_pair {|f,t| text.gsub! f, t}
```

#### [Here is a working demo](http://cibox.org/slivu/stackoverflow?lang=ruby&file=using-many-instances-of-gsub-in-ruby.rb&run=true)

Comment: If you're going to override `text` each time, you might as well just use `gsub!` instead, and skip the copy/assignment.

Comment: agree, thank you. sometimes the rush makes me ignore important details

Comment: Be careful here, one subtle difference between `gsub` and `gsub!` is that `gsub` will return the original value if the pattern is not found, `gsub!` will assign a `nil` if the pattern is not found.

Answer (score 1):

If you are always converting a particular pattern, namely words, then you can have a simple matching pattern and then replace depending on the word with just a single run of `gsub` per matching pattern.

```
def translate 
  @text
  .gsub(/[ \t]+/, " ")
  .gsub(/\w+/,
    "my" => "mine",
    "is" => "be",
    "y" => "ye",
    "t" => "te"
  )
end
```

This would be much faster than iterating multiple times for `gsub`.

Answer (score 0):

Building off of slivu's idea, here's a Perl-like alternative:

```
@text = '123 my 456 is 123y 456t 123t, 456t.'

def s(regex, string)
   @text.gsub!(regex, string)
end

s /my/, 'mine'
s /\sis\s/, ' be '
s /y\s/, 'ye '
s /t\s/, 'te '
s /t\,/, 'te,'
s /t\./, 'te.'

puts @text
```